# heating verses air conditioning

Tags: thermodynamics

My Co-workers and I are trying to figure this out, but can't think of a logical answer. It's probably an easy one, but I'll ask anyway-
Ok, the heater is set at 73 degrees. 
The a/c is set at 73 degrees. 
Why does it feel warmer with the heat on if they're both 73 degrees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Maybe it's your imagination
2) When the heater is on, its cold outside, so maybe it feels relatively warmer inside (and conversely for when the A/C is on)
3) Maybe the cold air from the A/C has more of a chilling effect than the warm air from the heater has a warming effect, thus making it feel colder with the A/C
4) Maybe something about the aerodynamics in your building i) increase the draftiness when the A/C is on (or its warmer outside), or ii) cause the thermostat to measure a lower temperature when the heat is on
5) Maybe the system is designed to over-heat more than it over-cools
6) Maybe something else